# why we go for angular while we have typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

Why we go for angular while we have the Typescript ?

I don't know we have typescript and JavaScript but why we are moving towards 
   angular.

angular also using Typescript as main file.

Comment: Typescript is a language written in js that Angular(that's a framework) use to code.

Comment: Typescript is a "programming langage" like javascript and Angular is simply a "framework" working with those languages

Comment: what is the main advantages for Angular?

Comment: @MuthukrishnanKandasamy Really i mean really. This question in SO. Why not going at angular.io to read it. Or you might be interested in some SO posts. Try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Angular you have:**

- code organization layers like modules, components, services
- all of above layers are easy to reuse and easy to test
- templates with two-way data binding
- a lot of services and libraries provided by other ppl (routing, ngBootstrap, calendars, HttpClient)

**In pure typescript** (which literally means pure JavaScript) you have to write everything by your own. You do not have any support and rules of framework.

Answer (score 2):

Angular is a framework that recommends using it with TypeScript.
why? https://vsavkin.com/writing-angular-2-in-typescript-1fa77c78d8e8

More official info on Angular with TypeScript:
https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration

Answer (score 2):

Angular is a framework where you can build spa (single page application) for building this kind of single page you can use either typescript or java script (typescript and java scripts are programming language). According to angular most recommended language for building application in angular is typescript because typescript provides a feature to use oop concepts that we used in c# or java And one more thing is Typescript is actually compile to java script(that is understand by browser) by using different kind of transpiler.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is an extension (a “superset”) of the JavaScript language. Internally they convert your ts code to javascript only. For eg.

```
In typescript you write a code for constant like 
const a = 10;
```

but if you want to achieve same thing in javascript, you have to write per below code

```
Object.defineProperty( obj, "a", {
 value: 10,
 writable: false,
 enumerable: true,
 configurable: true
});
```

TypeScript allows you to leverage ES6, ES2016, and ES2017 features and compile to JavaScript. Some of those features include:

```
Classes
Modules
Arrow Functions
```